# OpenLayers 6: trying to show label, getting error

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using OpenLayers 6, I'm trying to show label of the points I get with a Ajax query on a MariaDB server. The query works, the polyline is shown on the map indeed. However,it fails to execute the code about the points, lauching an error.

As a result I'd like to get for evert points with the coordinates from the array coordinate a label containing the text from the array nomiLuoghi.

This is the code:

```
var vettoreLinea = new ol.source.Vector();
var vettorePunti = new ol.source.Vector();

var riga = new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'rgba(200,0,0,1)', width: 2 });
var riempimento = new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'rgba(200,120,0,0.5)' });

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({layer: 'natural=yes'})
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vettoreLinea,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: riga
            })
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vettorePunti
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([7.6, 47.56]),
        zoom: 5
    })
});

var idviaggio = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].id.substring(1);

var res;
var dati = new FormData();
dati.append("id", idviaggio);
$.ajax({
    url: "php/get_Viaggio.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dati,
    success: function (resJ) {res = JSON.parse(resJ);},
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false
});

var coordinate = [];
var nomiLuoghi = [];
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    coordinate.push([res[i][0], res[i][1]]);
    nomiLuoghi.push(res[i][3]);
};

var linea = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinate);
linea.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var featureLinea = new ol.Feature({
    name: "LineaViaggio",
    geometry: linea
});
vettoreLinea.addFeature(featureLinea);

for (i = 0; i < coordinate.length; i++) {
    var marker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coordinate[i][0], coordinate[i][0]))
    });
    var stile = new ol.style.Style({
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                fill: riempimento,
                stroke: riga,
                radius: 5
            }),
            fill: riempimento,
            stroke: riga
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            label: nomiLuoghi[i],
            scale: 1.2,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#fff'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '0',
                width: 3
            })
        })
    });
    marker.setStyle(stile);
    vettorePunti.addFeature(marker);
};
```

This is the error I get in the consolle:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.getCode is not a function
Zr proj.js:401
Kr proj.js:421
Hr proj.js:438
qr proj.js:348
<anonymous> viaggio.js:68
```

Comment: `fromLonLat(coordinate[i][0], coordinate[i][0])` should be `fromLonLat([coordinate[i][0], coordinate[i][0]])`

Comment: Hi, thanks, that was the error, but now it still doesn't show any label. Have you any other ideas?

Comment: `label: nomiLuoghi[i]` should be `text: nomiLuoghi[i]`.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't change a thing, on the map only the polyline is shown, neither the point nor the labels.